# express.Createserver() not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am beginner to nodejs. I tried below code. But server is not listening to the port and host.

```js
var fs = require("fs");
var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("config.json"));
var host = config.host;
var port = config.port;
var express = require("express") ,http = require("http");

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
app.get("/", function(request, response){
    response.send("hello");
});
app.listen(port, host);
```

I also tried below code. But found in SO that this method is deprecated. And I replaced it with above code. Though it is not working. I also tried installing express globally then also not listening to port. What might be the problem.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express.createServer();
app.get('/', function(request, response){
response.send("hello");
});
app.listen(port, host);
```

This is my config file.

```
[{
     "host" : "127.0.0.1",
     "port" : 1337
}]
```

Comment: Any errors logged? Are you sure config file is read correctly? Please log the host and port to see what the server is being passed.

Comment: It works perfectly fine... print the `config` object to see if you are accessing the right port

Comment: I had edit my code with config file. I wrote `127.0.0.1:1337` in URL but it return connection failed. It doesn't return any error but it keep on like waiting to listen and nothings happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

config is array not object, you need to access it accordingly(or change the config) .Here is corrected code;

```
    var fs = require("fs");
    var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("config.json"));
    var host = config[0].host;
    var port = config[0].port;
    var express = require("express") ,http = require("http");

    var app = express();
    var server = http.createServer(app);
    app.get("/", function(request, response){
        response.send("hello");
    });
    var server = http.createServer(app);
app.get("/", function(request, response){
    response.send("hello");
});
var server = app.listen(port, host);
server.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('error:' + err);
});
server.on('listening', function(){
    console.log('server is up, all is well');
});
```

Comment: its not working.. Even i tried using internal assign of host and port.